# how browser react to display none?

Tags: html, twain

i want to understand if the display: none in html means that the element doesn't exist in the browser perspective ?
i have the following situation : 
i have a element that i use to repear a plugin

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" id="embedElement"
        TYPE="Application/DynamicWebTwain-Plugin"
        PLUGINSPAGE="/gestionRH/webTwain/DynamicWebTwain.xpi"> 
</embed>
```

the code javascript :

```
var Plugin = document.embeds[0];
```

when i put the embed element within a div and set display css attribute of this div into none 
javascript seems not to find this element 
what is the explanation ?

Comment: "display: none" removes the element from the page layout, but not from the DOM (it still exists in the page source). There must be some other reason why you can't find the element with javascript, I think.

Comment: yes because when i tried this :  alert($("#embedElement").attr('type'));  it works fine

Comment: why dont you try it once with document.getElementByID() ... I see no reason why the javascript cant find your element this way. But since its not working, get the element with its ID.

Comment: this var Plugin = document.getElementById('embedElement'); not working too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another technique to hide the element and still access it:

```
.hide {
   position: absolute !important;
   top: -9999px !important;
   left: -9999px !important;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/

Comment: i'll try it , but first i want to understand why it's not working because when i tried to  alert($("#embedElement").attr('type')); it works